# Is there a material that could "convert" near infrared frequency to infrared?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

I have a laser with a wavelength of 650 nm (visible red light) and was wondering if there is some sort of material that could be used to absorb and disperse a different frequency of light around (900 nm).

Energy would just be dissipated by the material as it is converted to a lower frequency,

Comment: I just thought that it possible to red-shift but that would take a far enough distance, so that solution is impractical.

Comment: You realize of course that any absorptive material will do that through  black body radiation but it will be a dispersed spectrum?  You want a coherent beam out of this, or at least a beam? http://www.rp-photonics.com/frequency_doubling.html for doubling frequency exists, not for halving though .

Comment: Yes I am looking for a directed beam. It should proceed like this: I take a red laser and direct it at the material and on another end a beam or one with little divergence is dispersed

Comment: What you are looking for is another laser. A converting material will not do.

Comment: Check out "CARS" and "CSRS" -- Stokes formalism for mixing wavelengths in a nonlinear material to generate sum/difference wavelengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a link for halving too:

[Nonclassical light generation](http://iopscience.iop.org/1464-4266/6/6/004;jsessionid=0DDD69FFBD88F20702C955CC8C1282C1.c1) in the process of self-frequency halving in a periodically poled active nonlinear Nd:Mg:LiNbO3 crystal

> Nonclassical light generation at self-frequency halving in periodically poled active nonlinear crystals is studied. The squeezing spectra of fundamental radiation and its subharmonic are investigated for a periodically poled Nd:Mg:LiNbO3 crystal.

It seems to be a matter of research at the present time, not something available for any laser beam in the manner you envisage.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming when you say the output is "dispersed" you mean it is incoherent and radiating in all directions, what you are asking for is a *fluorescent* material.

A Google search for "IR fluorescence" finds a couple of companies making these materials for biological sample marking, however the ones I checked into further need a slightly longer excitation wavelength to work efficiently.

If you actually want a coherent output beam, these or similar materials might be usable as the active medium in a dye laser to be pumped by your 650 nm beam.